# Add nonexistent ID to database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that starts at ID = 1000.  I want to add an entry at ID = 1.  I am using MySQL.  Also this will just be done once, and I do not care for the rest of the 2 - 999 values.  I am just concerned with adding something at ID = 1, this ID does not already exist so I cannot update it.

Comment: can't you use `INSERT INTO table (id, things) VALUES ("1","...")`

Comment: yes that works, put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply insert it and define the ID rather than allowing auto_increment to do its normal job.

```
INSERT INTO table
(id, another_column, ... )
VALUES
(1, 'some value', ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the id directly, when you insert the record:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`id`, `some_field`) VALUES ('1', 'Value');
```